# Can't figure out why video is not playing

Tags: flash, video, flv

I used the longtail flv player setup wizard to embed a video on a web page. It worked on the wizard but not after I copied and pasted into my page. Does anyone see anything obvious? The thumbnail for the screenshot works and is in the same location as the flv file.

???????

Link is [here](http://workforall.biz/workforall/)

Comment: How does it belong to superuser.com? Care to explain? :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly confident it's throwing a wobbly at the fact that you're including the flv file as:

```
so.addVariable('file','http://www.thurstonchamber.com/WorkForAll/ICANCap.flv');
```

Try just reducing it to:

```
 so.addVariable('file', 'ICANCap.flv');
```

and seeing if that work.

Comment: 'Throwing a wobbly' is the technical term of course, I can explain it more simply if you prefer?

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and still no difference. I'm really stumped!

Comment: Perhaps their server doesn't support flv? I ran into that a few months ago with another client.

Comment: That's very strange, because I grabbed your code from your server and tried it and it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help... see my comment below :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the fist thing that the Flash Debug play showed when I visited your site.

```
SecurityError: Error #2123: Security sandbox violation: Loader.content: http://workforall.biz/workforall/player.swf cannot access http://www.thurstonchamber.com/WorkForAll/thumb.jpg. No policy files granted access.
    at flash.display::Loader/get content()
    at com.jeroenwijering.player::Model/resizeHandler()
```

Flash is expecting to be able to reference a Jpeg of another domain, and there is nothing in the swf which is telling it that "This is allowable" so it is throwing an error.

Comment: Unless you have access to the code, you will need to put http://workforall.biz/workforall/player.swf and http://www.thurstonchamber.com/WorkForAll/thumb.jpg in the same folder.

Comment: Thanks for pointing things out to me... I must have mistyped in the wizard. I started from scratch and it works. My error was my own, not using the proper file path. Sorry all!